# Video upload and playback in Flowplayer using Amazon S3 and other webservices

Tags: video, amazon-s3, streaming, amazon-web-services, flowplayer

I'm looking to do the following. I was hoping you expert could review the steps and let me know if it is possible, or at which step does my plan fall apart. I apologize if this format is not effective, but I think seeing my thought process in steps will be best. Thank you so much.

1. Purchase an Amazon S3 storage account (start with trial)
2. Create uploader on my website that will allow users to upload to the
   Amazon storage (web uploader)
3. Create custom-coded database that will link video
   metadata on website (Title, User, Views, Date, etc) to the actual
   file address on Amazon storage. This step is important, as it will
   allow a user who uploaded a video to remove a video, change the
   video title on the website, and more.
4. Custom-code webpage to locate file address based on video id (step 3-database)
5. Custom-code webpage to play that file from Amazon storage in
   Flowplayer flash player

Hopefully these steps convey my goal.

**My questions:**

1. Flowplayer accepts the following file formats: FLV, H.264, MP4. Out of convenience, I would want to take care of file conversion for my users, as I assume that is what YouTube and the big video companies do. How can I do this in step 2 (video upload)?
2. Step 3, which is setting up the database to link Amazon S3 storage to the actual users/video metadata on my site seems somewhat complicated. Does Amazon have a service that takes care of all of this for me (easily?)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

1. You would upload to an Intermediate server where you would encode the videos in the desired formats before storing them on S3. EC2 would probably be a good fit here as transfers between EC2 and S3 are free and very fast.

   [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is a common tool used to convert videos or you might consider a 3rd party solution like [encoding.com](http://www.encoding.com/) Most of the big players in this space support pulling and pushing to S3 natively too.
2. Amazon doesn't really have any service to index and track your S3 videos. Whilst you can query S3 using the APIs or add metadata to S3 objects, you're definitely better off tracking everything in your own database. Use whatever database you are comfortable with - you only need to store the S3 **bucket** and **key** (filename) of each file along with any other user data you wish to link.

Comment: Geoff, are you saying here that EC2 can do the conversion for me for free?? You confused me by answering my first question with a comment about EC2 acting as an intermediate server, and then went right into a whole thing about FFmpeg and encoding.com.

Comment: No - not for free. You would be paying for the server and would be responsible to creating and managing the entire encoding process. (possibly using ffmpeg to do the encoding). With encoding.com or similar services, I think you can point them to your files on S3 and they download, encode and then send them back to S3. Easier than doing it yourself if your encoding requirements are straightforward but probably more expensive too.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. Btw hope you had a nice Thanksgiving (if you celebrate).  Have you heard of Kaltura.com (the non-free service as opposed to Kaltura.org)? They are, from what I've read briefly, a big player in the video streaming space, and their service takes care of storage AND encoding in one package. It may be something I want to consider as an easier solution, but wondering if you have any experience with it.

Comment: Sorry, I've not heard of them at all and I'm in the UK so no Thanksgiving for me... Here are some links for you: http://www.brightcove.com/en/ , http://www.encoding.com/aws , http://heywatch.com/page/home , http://viddler.com/ , http://www.bitgravity.com/ , http://www.ooyala.com/

Comment: @pr0tocol: I'd suggest you to look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3931145 .