# Amazon S3 with flowplayer

Tags: amazon-s3, flowplayer

Where can I find some material to stream videos from S3 bucket to play with flowplayer on my website?

Comment: Try this : http://flowplayer.org/forum/7/17099
also you can follow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245860/video-upload-and-playback-in-flowplayer-using-amazon-s3-and-other-webservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually is simple. Just give the link of the S3 object to flowplayer. There is nothing special to be done here.